# Custom \theparagraph if \subsubsection no exists

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

Trying to redefine `\theparagraph` to output number according to existence or not of `\subsubsection`.

```
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{
    \ifthenelse
    {\equal{\value{subsubsection}}{0}}
    {\thesubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
    {\thesubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}
}
```

But it is not working.
Is this the best way to achieve a behavior where paragraphs are numbered under sections and and subsections?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! 'Not working' is not really helpful. The redefinition depends on the underlying documentclass and/or other packages. Please provide a full document. I also think that `\ifthenelse` is not necessary here, `\ifnum` is already provided by TeX.SX

Comment: Did you use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` too? With your code and `article` class (for example) I see the relevant paragraph numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Expandability of the contents is an issue here. Below I've used primitive conditionals to decide whether `\subsubsection` has been used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% Number sectional units up to \paragraph

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
    \thesubsection
  \else
    \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  .\arabic{paragraph}}


\begin{document}

\section{A section}% Level 1
\subsection{A subsection} % Level 2
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}% Level 3
\paragraph{A paragraph}% Level 4

\section{A section}% Level 1
\subsection{A subsection} % Level 2
%\subsubsection{A subsubsection}% Level 3
\paragraph{A paragraph}% Level 4

\section{A section}% Level 1
%\subsection{A subsection} % Level 2
%\subsubsection{A subsubsection}% Level 3
\paragraph{A paragraph}% Level 4

\end{document}
```

Note how **Section 3** illustrates a problem in your logic, if you don't have a `\subsection`, but still use `\paragraph`. This may be avoided through nesting:

```
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      \thesection
    \else
      \thesubsection
    \fi
  \else
    \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  .\arabic{paragraph}}
```

Above I've added another layer within the conditional. However, at this point, you may want to consider why your document structure is not following the regular guidelines.

The end result may be ambiguity in your numbering scheme.

Comment: Not your fault, but if a `\subsubsection` is invoked after a `\subsection`'s `\paragraph`, it shares the same number as the paragraph before it.  Very ambiguous.

Comment: That ambiguity doesn't happen in my document.